# DNS Named could not be restarted

Tags: linux, dns, centos, cpanel, whm

Recently i got a problem with DNS Server saying that "Named could not be restarted". I tried of trying with so many commands suggest most of the blog and websites. I could not find a way to fix that.

I have tried with godaddy support team also, they said there was a problem with your DNS server. And i am unable to start the DNS Server with command (service named start).

Finally, I have tried with the command rebuilddnsconfig. It is saying that there was an error in the named.conf and i do not know how to rectify the problem.

```
root@ip-213-128-124-232 [/home/explorei]# /scripts/rebuilddnsconfig
Named could not be restarted, any obvious config errors should show up below this line.
WARNING: /etc/named.conf appears to contain errors which could not be corrected automatically!
/etc/named.conf:4: unknown key 'rndc-key'
/etc/rndc.key:1: key '': bad key name
/etc/rndc.key:1: key '': bad key name
/etc/rndc.key:1: key '': bad key name
mem.c:1246: REQUIRE(ctx->references == 1) failed, back trace
#0 0x2aab224a16c6 in ??
#1 0x2aab224a189a in ??
#2 0x2aab224b37a2 in ??
#3 0x403571 in ??
#4 0x2aab23afacdd in ??
#5 0x4025d9 in ??
Please correct these errors manually and rerun /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/fixrndc
```

Please suggest me how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file, or the key file are invalid.

If you have not made deliberate changes and had a basic working configuration, look for .rpmsave files in /etc, for originals.

Comment: I have got the below one when i locate for rpmsave.

root@ip-213-128-124-232 [/home/explorei]# locate rpmsave
/opt/cpanel/php/53/.depdb.rpmsave
/opt/cpanel/php/53/.filemap.rpmsave
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/etc/php.ini.rpmsave. I dont find its original file in the server.